# INDEX+MATCH ArrayFormula Return 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've been using StackOverflow for months and it has answered all of my questions, expect for the issue I'm currently having. I can't seem to fix the issue, no matter the options posted on this site. Maybe you can see the issue, that I'm not seeing at the moment.

I have one FormulaArray in VBA that takes the index of an external file, matches one value (Q2) with a value in column B of the external file. Then it matches a second value (P2) with a value in column D of the external file. If there's a match on both, it'll return a value that is in column C of the external file.

Works great in Excel, but the moment I create a Selection.FormulaArray = this formula, I get a 1004 in return. The line itself is shorter than 255 characters and even breaking up the INDEX and MATCH formulas into two parts (by Dim formulapart1 and formulapart2 as string) it doesn't work.

```
=INDEX([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$A:$D;MATCH(1;([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$B:$B=Q2)*([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$D:$D=P2);0);3)
```

I tried the following solution that was posted on this website that worked for others, but it's not working for me, no matter what I do:

```
Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
Dim theFormulaPart2 As String

theFormulaPart1 = "=INDEX([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$A:$D;XX"
theFormulaPart2 = "MATCH(1;([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$B:$B=Q2)*([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$D:$D=P2);0);3)"

With ActiveSheet.Range("DS2")
    .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
    .Replace "XX", theFormulaPart2
End With
```

Comment: 1.  The formula has to be viable so instead of `XX` use `999`.  2.  when using vba to insert a formula, one needs to use `en-us` format.  replace the `;` with `,`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottCraner! I was about to flip the table in the office after spending two hours on this formula, coming to find out this simple solution. Thanks a lot for waking me up, mate!

Comment: @ScottCraner Why does the formula have to be split in two, is it too long for VBA to insert?

Comment: As @ScottCraner said, `theFormulaPart1` needs to be viable as a stand-alone formula - currently, you're not closing the brackets!  Try `theFormulaPart1="=INDEX([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$A:$D;999;3)", and remove `;3)` from the end of `theFormulaPart2`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chronocidal. I got it all working. This thing made me nuts. Dwirony is right by the way, it's all working at the moment. We're working in a French environment (although I'm dutch and working with an en-US environemnt). I have this continuous issue with the semicolon and comma, not knowing that the comma was necessary in the VBA script. Thanks a lot all, all sorted!

Comment: @YassinKulk If it's all fixed, please remember to "Accept" the answer to remove this from the "Unanswered questions" list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues with how you have split the code (your `theFormulaPart1` is not a valid formula on its own!) but that's not the *real* issue here - that's your ["XY Problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The *real* issue is that when putting a Formula in via VBA, unless you are using `.FormulaLocal`, you **must** use the English localisations - this means using `,` intead of `;` to separate the arguments.  And, there is no `.FormulaArrayLocal`, so for an Array formula you always use the English localisation:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("DS2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$A:$D,MATCH(1,([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$B:$B=Q2)*([ISOCODE.xlsx]ISOCODE!$D:$D=P2),0),3)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever working with excel-VBA (or with anything in general), try always to start from something smaller, that works. In your case, remove the opend worksheet and try to make it work with the one you have. Thus, here is something that works:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
    Dim theFormulaPart2 As String

    theFormulaPart1 = "=INDEX(A:D,XX"
    theFormulaPart2 = "MATCH(1,(B:B=Q2)*(D:D=P2),0),3)"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("E1")
        theFormulaPart1 = Replace(theFormulaPart1, "XX", theFormulaPart2)
        .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
    End With

End Sub
```

Once you fix it, go further and include `[ISOCODE!.xlsx]`

Comment: Hi Vityata - I asked Scott above but I'll ask again because I'm curious... Why not just insert the formula as `"=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(1,(B:B=Q2)*(D:D=P2),0),3)"`? What's the purpose of the `Replace`?

Comment: @dwirony - no idea. I did it because the OP has decided to do it this way. Probably he can control the string code a bit better.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like unnecessary steps.. oh well!

Comment: @dwirony `.FormulaArray` has a character limit, 255, in this case it is not needed. But sometimes the only way to do it is to first do a viable formula as the array then edit the formula.

Comment: @Vityata you will need to have a viable formula for the first part: `theFormulaPart1 = "=INDEX(A:D,9999,3)"` then on the second just the MATCH: `"MATCH(1,(B:B=Q2)*(D:D=P2),0)" then replace the `999` with the second.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yup, I got the idea now, removed the comment.

Comment: Thanks for all the help all! Got this 1004 bugging thing out the way now. Indeed, the spitting of the .FormulaArray is not necessary in this case, but I have future calculations that'll definitely go past the 255 character mark. In that case it would work. Thanks a lot again for the help and quick support!